# how to recreate view which is one of layout children

Tags: android, android-layout, view, recreate

I have tablelayout which is one of children of my mainLayout. My tablelayout have something about 50 cells.
I fill some cells which depends on data taken from server. After clicking button put new data to this table, and here is the problem. Is there any way to recreate it/ refresh it, cause I want to have clean table again, it should look like before first data inserting.

I try with:

```
tableLayout.invalidate();
```

but it doesn't works, most of post is about whole layout not about one of children

There is for sure some primitive answer for this like:

- save which cells was changed and then clean it,
- clean all cells.

But I'm ask about something else like tablelayout.invalidate() but it need to work.

Comment: smth means smooth or something. For your kind info , In StackOverflow, please don't add sms text.

Comment: I search for some way to just reacreate this view to state created in xml code

Comment: @Gunaseelan thx for info I try to avoid this kind of text